# Мост оплачен на половину или наполовину?

Tags: орфография

Мост оплачен на половину или наполовину?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **Мост оплачен наполовину.**

НАПОЛОВИНУ, нареч. 1. Одной половиной; на одну половину. Уменьшить срок н. Стакан н. пуст. Цветы в букете н. белые, н. жёлтые. 2. **Не до конца, не совсем**; в некоторой степени, отчасти. Н. забыть, понимать.

**Парные варианты** с раздельным написанием:

Цеха загружены на половину мощностей. Такси в Шереметьево было заказано на половину девятого.  Она заглянула на половину хозяев.