# Верно написание «наполовину»?

Tags: наречия

Это наполовину больше, чем в прошлом году.

Answer (score 1):

Верно, это же наречие,  как Вы сами отметили. А в чём сомнение?

Существительным было бы в предложении: Остановились на половине дороги. Прошли на другую половину дома.

Comment: Людмила, в Нацкорпусе есть и так и так (хотя в основном слитно) , в интернете тоже. Ведь можно спросить "насколько больше?" - наполовину и  "на сколько больше?" - на половину. В чем я неправ?

Comment: По-моему, насколько больше?-наполовину - единственно верно, а вот "на сколько" больше требует дополнения "чего":  На сколько книг больше здесь? - На половину того, что есть там.

Comment: Нацкорпус не может служить примером грамотности, это не учебная литература. В художественной литературе, особенно современной, тоже есть ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

**Это наполовину больше, чем в прошлом году** (наречие, слитное написание). Наречия надо отличать от существительных с предлогом НА.

**1) Существительное**

ПОЛОВИНА, 1. Одна из двух равных частей, вместе составляющих целое. П. яблока, комнаты, состояния. 2. Середина какого-л. расстояния, ёмкости, промежутка времени и т.п. **Остановиться на половине дороги.** 3. Отдельная часть помещения (преимущественно жилого). Жилая, летняя п. избы.

**Существительное "половина" управляет другим существительным:** прервать на половине (чего?) фразы, работы выполнены на половине (чего?) объектов

**2) Наречие**

НАПОЛОВИНУ, нареч. 1. Одной половиной; на одну половину. Уменьшить срок н. Стакан н. пуст. Цветы в букете н. белые, н. жёлтые. 2. Не до конца, не совсем; в некоторой степени, отчасти. Н. забыть, понимать.

ВПОЛОВИНУ, нареч. =Наполовину. В. меньше. В. снизить потери.

Наречие **может относится  к глаголу, к прилагательному, к другому наречию**.  Иногда можно сделать проверку подстановкой синонимичного наречия:  Это **наполовину (вполовину, вдвое)** больше, чем в прошлом году.

**Примеры:** Его гардероб **наполовину** состоит из белых рубашек. Её атмосфера **более чем наполовину** состоит из воды.

Answer (score 1):

Слитное или раздельное написание слов **наполовину** и **на половину** зависит от того, какой частью речи они являются.

**1.** Пишется слитно, если к слову можно задать вопрос **«как?»**. В этом случае перед нами наречие:
*Эта проблема решена **наполовину.***

**2.** Пишется раздельно, если можно задать **падежный вопрос «куда?», «на что?»** или вставить определение между «на» и «половину». В таком случае перед нами существительное «половина» с предлогом «на»:

***На половину*** стола положите все книги.
*Я положил книги **на*** [свою] ***половину*** стола.

В Вашем предложении правильно так:
**Это *наполовину больше,* чем в прошлом году.**

Можно найти достаточно похожих примеров:

*Астрономы считают, что Млечный Путь **наполовину больше, чем** считалось ранее.*
Правительственный портал: *Украинцы вкладывают в товары и услуги **наполовину** **больше, чем** три года назад.*
*В этом году интерес к ярмарке вырос, поскольку...организаций зарегистрировалось почти **наполовину больше, чем** в прошлом году...*

P.S. Совсем недавно Вы уже задавали похожий вопрос:
 [**Мост оплачен на половину или наполовину?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429169/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)